# bazel projects: how to add system include path?

Tags: bazel, google-coral

I try to build pycoral from google-coral. It is a bazel project. It requires a lot, also cc_toolchain.
In cc_toolchain there are some include path configured, but not for my system (openSUSE Tumbleweed).
So the bazel build claims:

```
undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@flatbuffers//src:flatbuffers':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'flatbuffers/src/util.cpp':
  '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/10/include-fixed/limits.h'
  '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/10/include-fixed/syslimits.h'
  '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/10/include/stdint.h'
  '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/10/include/stddef.h'
  '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/10/include/stdarg.h'
Target //src:_pywrap_coral failed to build
```

I grepped a while through the bazel cache files and found the configured include paths in "external/crosstool/cc_toolchain_config.bzl".

```
CXX_BUILTIN_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES = {
"k8": [
    "/usr/include/c++/%d" % GCC_VERSION,
    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/%d" % GCC_VERSION,
    "/usr/include/c++/%d/backward" % GCC_VERSION,
    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/%d/include" % GCC_VERSION,
    "/usr/local/include",
    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/%d/include-fixed" % GCC_VERSION,
    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
    "/usr/include",
],
```

How can I add my own include paths?

Regards

Daniel